# How to align nodes using forest package, tikz tier

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest, trees

I've created the following tree using the forest package. However I cannot understand how to align m,n,S,F and L. I used a previous question ([Tier in Forest tree- how to align properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573025/tier-in-forest-tree-how-to-align-properly/573038?noredirect=1#comment1443686_573038)) to try to fix it but this time it is not working. Thank you in advance

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}, 
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,
           anchor=north}{}
           },
                            }
            }
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$\Omega$, empty nodes[M[m, tier=1][n, tier=1]][[S, tier=1][[F, tier=1][L, tier=1]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case this works:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles,
          text height=1.5ex, 
          anchor=center
          },
delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},  
%
[$\Omega$, 
    [M
        [m,tier=L3]
        [n,tier=L3]
    ]
    [
        [S,tier=L3]
            [
                [F,tier=L3]
                [L,tier=L3]
            ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]